# How can I stitch bottom of some image to topside of another image by erasing as much overlapped image as possible?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, feature-extraction, stitching

I have 2 images of size 1920*1080 and I want to try image-stitching on them. These are images (images are from wind turbine blade.)

This is the first image

[image: image 1]

And the second image.

[image: image 2]

I already have found and used plenty of github repositoties that have implemented the image stitching on directory of images, but my images as you can see are very similar and I decided to do it myself. one thing that might come in handy is that image 2 has to be stitched in bottom of image 1 in the way that remove the overlapped parts.

How can I use this point to use in my code here:

https://github.com/WillBrennan/ImageStitching

```
import os
import argparse
import logging

import cv2

import image_stitching

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('image_paths', type=str, nargs='+', help="paths to one or more images or image directories")
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--debug', dest='debug', action='store_true', help='enable debug logging')
    parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', dest='quiet', action='store_true', help='disable all logging')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--display', dest='display', action='store_true', help="display result")
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--save', dest='save', action='store_true', help="save result to file")
    parser.add_argument("--save_path", dest='save_path', default="stitched.png", type=str, help="path to save result")
    parser.add_argument('-k', '--knn', dest='knn', default=2, type=int, help="Knn cluster value")
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--lowe', dest='lowe', default=0.7, type=float, help='acceptable distance between points')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--min', dest='min_correspondence', default=10, type=int, help='min correspondences')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.debug:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger("main")

    logging.info("beginning sequential matching")

    if image_stitching.helpers.is_cv2():
        sift = cv2.SIFT()
    elif image_stitching.helpers.is_cv3():
        sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("error! unknown version of python!")

    result = None
    result_gry = None

    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher({'algorithm': 0, 'trees': 5}, {'checks': 50})

    image_paths = args.image_paths
    image_index = -1
    for image_path in image_paths:
        if not os.path.exists(image_path):
            logging.error('{0} is not a valid path'.format(image_path))
            continue
        if os.path.isdir(image_path):
            extensions = [".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"]
            for file_path in os.listdir(image_path):
                if os.path.splitext(file_path)[1].lower() in extensions:
                    image_paths.append(os.path.join(image_path, file_path))
            continue

        logging.info("reading image from {0}".format(image_path))
        image_colour = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_colour, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

        image_index += 1

        if image_index == 0:
            result = image_colour
            result_gry = image_gray
            continue

        logger.debug('computing sift features')
        features0 = sift.detectAndCompute(result_gry, None)
        features1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_gray, None)

        matches_src, matches_dst, n_matches = image_stitching.compute_matches(features0, features1, flann, knn=args.knn)

        if n_matches < args.min_correspondence:
            logger.error("error! too few correspondences")
            continue

        logger.debug("computing homography between accumulated and new images")
        H, mask = cv2.findHomography(matches_src, matches_dst, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
        result = image_stitching.combine_images(image_colour, result, H)

        if args.display and not args.quiet:
            image_stitching.helpers.display('result', result)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        result_gry = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    logger.info("processing complete!")

    if args.display and not args.quiet:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    if args.save:
        logger.info("saving stitched image to {0}".format(args.save_path))
        image_stitching.helpers.save_image(args.save_path, result)
```

Comment: Are the two images cross registered already?

Comment: There are total number of 15 images. the images above are the shots right behind each other. As I mentioned in question "image 2 has to be stitched in bottom of image 1".

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam that doesn't answer A_A's question, sadly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry.I don't know what does cross-registered mean!

Comment: It means that you have determined points in both images that are the the same points.

Comment: Yeah of course. There are points that are in both images. You probably can follow the strips in the left side of turbine blade in both images and match the similarities in both.